# Change textSize in a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, text-size

In this code below from an android application on android studio, I have a LinearLayout that contains a TextView whose size I want to change for example say from 100 to 20. But the thing is, whenever I change the **android:textSize="100.0dip"** to any other number, the size still remains the same in the application when running it on my phone.

Code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@id/qp_body_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/widget34"
    android:layout_below="@id/widget99"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="right">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@id/qp_body_wrapper_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/qp_body"
            style="@style/QuoteViewText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboard_qod_bg"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10.0dip"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="100.0dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat,RtlHardcoded" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and here is the QuoteViewText style :

```
<style name="QuoteViewText">
        <item name="android:textSize">100.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fffcfcfc</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#ff102e46</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">1.0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: is of the same size the container of the text?

Comment: I am new to android and java, but I edited the code in here, I copied the whole scrollView , that answers your question ?

Comment: Try to use sp or only dp instead to dip

Comment: I already did, but nothing changed :/

Comment: Try to use only integer numbers, like a 100, without the dots.

Comment: Oh dear, to change it back to 20 dip (use sp for text sizes) you need to put 20 dip to TextView in XML.

Comment: I did all the above solution but none of them worked

Comment: Try to remove `android:textSize` from the `TextView` and keep it just in a `QuoteViewText` and then change it in style ... or do the same but vice versa

Answer (score 1):

**Tip**: Use `dimens.xml` to store your concrete values for easier and cleaner code management.

Besides the change from `dip` to `sp` and the superfluous double setting of `textSize`, there is no problem with your `TextView` code and it should work fine. There some other small issues as possibly using `@+id/qp_body` instead and using `match_parent` instead of the deprecated `fill_parent`, but still it should be working.

This is shooting in the dark, but check, if you are not somehow overwriting the value programatically in code. If not, you could always try to and see what happens:

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qp_body);
mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20f);
```

Or using a dimension resource:

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qp_body);
mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_text_size));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **dip** in textsize,instead of that just use **dp** or **sp**.dp and sp both will work but normally in textview ,we use **sp** .

Answer (score 0):

You are setting textview size 2 times one from applying style and another from applying textsize for the textview. Use any one. And for texts use sp instead of dp to honour user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Text size is measured in `sp` - Scale-independent Pixels.

So, in your case you should use

```
<item name="android:textSize">100sp</item>
```

instead

```
<item name="android:textSize">100.0dip</item>
```

Also, don't forget that style is overrided by properties from your layout, in this case you should remove `android:textSize` from your `TextView` and leave it just in styles. Also you should start from a text size of 10, 100 is to big and never used.

Comment: I did everything you said here, but nothing has changed !!

Answer (score 0):

You are using **dip** , instead you should **sp** for *textSize*.

you can update your code files with these below files , it will solve your problem

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@id/qp_body_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/widget34"
    android:layout_below="@id/widget99"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="right">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@id/qp_body_wrapper_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/qp_body"
            style="@style/QuoteViewText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboard_qod_bg"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dpp"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat,RtlHardcoded" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and here is the QuoteViewText style :

```
 <style name="QuoteViewText">
            <item name="android:textSize">100sp</item>
            <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#fffcfcfc</item>
            <item name="android:shadowColor">#ff102e46</item>
            <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
            <item name="android:shadowDy">1.0</item>
            <item name="android:shadowRadius">2.0</item>
        </style>
```